# ¿ Como puedo correr un WebService .asmx creado en Visual Studio 2008 para Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, webservice, visual-studio-2017

Tengo creado unos WebServices asmx  de hace tiempo con Visual Studio 2008. No puedo aprovecharlos para un proyecto nuevo que estoy creando en  Visual Studio 2017. ¿ Tengo que convertirlos a otro formato ?

Comment: si estas creando un proyecto nuevo con tecnologías mas actuales creo que lo mas sano es crear un asmx en el nuevo proyecto y hacer copy paste del código del anterior asmx

Comment: El problema es que son muchos webservices con bastante código y funciones. Necesito que pueda leerlo Visual Studio 2017 o en todo caso una herramienta que lo pasara  a otro formato

Comment: la cosa es que muy probablemente tu webservice de visual 2008 haya usado una librería .NET diferente y al intentar abrirlo o de plano no te dejará o si te dejará abrirlo le cambiara la librería .NET y de mostrará una serie de conflictos por solucionar, como dije lo mas sano es hacer un copy paste y resolver conflictos que probablemente sean menos que intentar directamente abrirlo con visual 2017

Comment: Que formato entonces usa Visual Studio 2017 para crear Web service tipo asmx ?

Comment: también son asmx pero el problema es la librería .NET muy probablemente sea una diferente